# What algorithm does the convhull() function in Matlab use?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, computational-geometry, convex-hull

What algorithms do the [`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) and [`convhulln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhulln.html) functions in MATLAB implement to compute the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

I cannot find any references..

Comment: According to http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhulln.html 
"convhulln is based on Qhull. For information about Qhull, see http://www.qhull.org/." I assume, same holds for `convhull`. See also `qhull.m`

Comment: @gevang Why don't you leave this as the answer so it does not show up as unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

*(making my comment an answer)*

According to MathWorks [convhulln](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhulln.html) documentation

> *"convhulln is based on Qhull. For information about Qhull, see http://www.qhull.org/"*

See also `qhull.m` for more info.

Barber, C. B., D.P. Dobkin, and H.T. Huhdanpaa, "[The Quickhull Algorithm for Convex Hulls](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/235815.235821)," ACM Trans. on Mathematical Software, 22(4), 1996.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, both `convhull` and `convhulln` used the [Qhull library](http://www.qhull.org/) internally.

Then starting with R2009b, `convhull` switched to using the [CGAL library](http://www.cgal.org/) as implementation, (but not `convhulln`).

---

If you go through the release notes, you can confirm these facts:

- In [R2009a release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes-older.html#bryg9vd-2):

> #### Upgrade to Computational Geometry
>
> MATLAB includes a new object-oriented suite of computational geometry
>   tools, together with a new underlying library called CGAL. The new
>   library provides improved robustness, performance, and memory
>   efficiency. The new tools are presented in three classes:
>
> - New class `TriRep` provides topological and geometric queries for triangulations in 2-D and 3-D space.
> - New class `DelaunayTri` provides increased functionality for Delaunay triangulation including topological and geometric queries,
>     incremental modification, and edge constraints.
> - New class `TriScatteredInterp` provides fast robust scattered data interpolation and a new natural-neighbor interpolation technique.

- Then in the [R2009b release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes-older.html#br7v2hm):

> #### Computational Geometry Functions Being Changed
>
> 2- and 3-D computational geometry functions (`delaunay`, `convhull`,
>   `griddata`, `voronoi`, `delaunay3`, `griddata3`) no longer use QHULL
>   or the QHULL options arguments. The N-D functions `gridatan`,
>   `delaunayn`, `convhulln`, and `voronoin` still use QHULL.
>
> ...

- Finally in [R2013a release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btpx7z7), those classes were deprecated in favor of the currently preferred methods:

> #### `scatteredInterpolant` class that replaces `TriScatteredInterp`
>
> `TriScatteredInterp` will be removed in a future release. Use the new
>   `scatteredInterpolant` class instead. The `scatteredInterpolant` class
>   performs interpolation on 2-D and 3-D scattered data with support for
>   extrapolation outside the convex hull of the sample points.
>   `scatteredInterpolant` also supports queries in grid vector format to
>   conserve memory.
>
> ...
>
> #### `triangulation` class to replace `TriRep`
>
> `TriRep` will be removed in a future release. Use the new `triangulation` class instead. The `triangulation` class represents 2-D and 3-D triangulations using a
>   similar form and syntax as `TriRep`.
>
> ...
>
> #### `delaunayTriangulation` class to replace `DelaunayTri`
>
> `DelaunayTri` will be removed in a future release. Use the new
>   `delaunayTriangulation` class instead. `delaunayTriangulation`
>   represents 2-D and 3-D Delaunay triangulations using a similar form
>   and syntax as `DelaunayTri`.
>
> ...

---

TL;DR:

- [`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) is based on [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/).
- [`convhulln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhulln.html) is based on [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/).